# How to have different video players for different user accounts in online video streaming

Tags: javascript, html, web, video-streaming

I am using a virtual classroom course. Class room videos are recorded and then it is streamed through a website. The said recorded videos are stored in cloud. I  have got a user login and password.But the video player A, which they the vendor use to stream isn't compatible with my device. I tried many techniques physically
 to correct as per their customer support but of no use.Wen this issue occured for the first time, they changed my player A to player B.Player B  was working fine on my device.But they changed again to player A without me knowing.Wen I asked them to change my player to B, they say it is not possible due to technical issues. What could be those technical limitations this time? Any guess( I am just awailing their services )
Note:There are many other user accounts and devices where their streaming service working fine.

Comment: I encourage you to clarify your question  & supply code, because from this description I have no idea what you're asking. Please clarify (by editing the actual question - not in the comments) and supply some code. :)

Comment: try this on ur code -> defaultPlayer = playerA
if(defaultPlayer != notworking) { defaultPlayer=playerB } if this doesn't help refer to 1st comment.